# Maximum of two factor variables

Tags: r

I have two factor variables which are frequency of Facebook use (FB_use) and that of Instagram use (Instagram_use). These variables have the following categories:

1. Never
2. Rarely (once or twice a month)
3. Sometimes ( once or twice a week)
4. Often times (a couple of times a day)

I want to make a new variable called Social Network usage frequency (Social_Network), which is the maximum of these two variables. For example, if an individual responds 1 (never) for Instagram and 3 (sometimes) for Facebook, this column (Social Network usage frequency) must give me the value of 3. By the way, I do not want to add a new column in my data. The reason is that I defined these two variables (Instagram and Facebook) from my data by recoding them. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you make your factors ordered - like `blah <- ordered(1:3, labels=c("Never","Rarely","Often"))` you can do things like `max(blah)` and even `pmax(blah1, blah2)` to take the parallel maximum of two ordinal variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare factors like this to generate a maximum. To do so convert them to characters first, like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

# Make up some data
dta <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,1,2), 
                  TW=c("1-Never", "1-Never", "2-Sometimes", "3-Often"), 
                  FB=c("2-Sometimes", "3-Often", "1-Never", "2-Sometimes"))

# Convert to character
dta$FB <- as.character(dta$FB)
dta$TW <- as.character(dta$TW)
dta %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   summarise(Max=max(FB, TW))

#output
#  ID    Max        
#  <dbl> <chr>      
#   1    2-Sometimes
#   2    3-Often
```